# Scripting that allows for the clearing of a cell if two other cells in the same row are blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get this script up and running and there are some issues. Essentially when the value selected from a drop down menu in column K is marked 'Approved' then I want it to see if columns M and N are empty and if so to clear column K.

Right now when I run this below and select 'Approved' from the drop down there is no change that occurs.

```
// Checks to see if Account Manager Status as been marked as 'Approved' if it has and there is no PO or Exception then the Account Manager Status will remain blank.
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColK) {
  var stateK = changedRanged.getValue()
  // begin switch statement for determining if Account Manager Status reads 'approved'
  switch (stateK) {
    case "Approved":
      if (ColM.isBlank && ColN.isBlank)
      {
        stateK.clear;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to be short and to the point

Comment: Does each row have a dropdown in column K? Are you saying that you want the dropdown automatically switched from 'Approved' to some blank value if M and N are empty?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was hoping for. Each row has a dropdown in column K with a few different values. We're trying to make it so that if it reads 'Approved' but those other two columns in that same row, M and N, are empty it keeps the value in column K blank.